# hive add partition statement ignores leading zero

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I've folder on hdfs
`/user/test/year=2016/month=04/dt=25/000000_0`

Need to add this above partition path to a **test** table.

command :

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (year=2016,month=04,dt=25)
```

But this add partition command is ignoring the leading zero in the month partition and creates an extra folder inside 2016 as month=4.
  `/user/test/year=2016/month=04/`
  `/user/test/year=2016/month=4/`
and table will be pointed to `/user/test/year=2016/month=4/` this path which doesn't contain any data.

I've checked the logs which says
`WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.BaseSemanticAnalyzer  - Partition Spec month=04 has been changed to month=4`

Please let me know if anyone faced this kind of issue and how to avoid this?

Hive version is : 1.2.1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using integer type for partitions. If you need leading zeros than use string partitions and quotes: `ALTER TABLE test ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (year='2016',month='04',dt='25')`

Comment: yeah I used quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE test` if partition folders already created. It will scan all directories and create new partitions. For more details visit [Hive Language Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)). Or you should use STRING for partition columns instead of INT.