# Hive creates partitions with leading zero

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I'm using hive **Hive 1.0.0-amzn-3**, 
In this version hive creates partitions dynamically, it ignores the type of the partition field type. In my case it creates partitions with leading zero, while field type is Integer.

```
day_ts=16/hour_ts=05
```

When I've upgraded hive to **Hive 2.1.1-amzn-0**
the behavior changed, the new partitions aligned with the type of the field and leading zero removed.

```
day_ts=16/hour_ts=4
```

Appreciate any lead to how allow hive 2.1 to keep the leading zero.
thanks.

**Here is an example**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `partitions_hell`(
  `a` string COMMENT,
  `b` string COMMENT  
  )
PARTITIONED BY (
  `day_ts` bigint,
  `hour_ts` int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'

LOCATION
  's3://xarkadiy-snbx/partitions_hell'

TBLPROPERTIES (
  'orc.compress'='SNAPPY'
)
```

Run Following query in hive 1.0.0

```
INSERT INTO TABLE partitions_hell_arkadiy partition(day_ts=16, hour_ts=05)
SELECT '11',
       'rwr'
FROM partitions_hell_arkadiy
```

Run Following query in hive 2.1.0

```
INSERT INTO TABLE partitions_hell_arkadiy partition(day_ts=16, hour_ts=04)
select '131', 'rw33rr'
from  partitions_hell_arkadiy
```

Result:

```
hive> show partitions default.partitions_hell
    > ;
OK

day_ts=16/hour_ts=05
day_ts=16/hour_ts=4
Time taken: 0.111 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

Comment: There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017321/hive-add-partition-statement-ignores-leading-zero) in other SO question.